# How do I get a date selector field in a content entity?

Tags: forms, 8, entities

I have a content entity in Drupal 8 that generates form for datetime. I just want to show only the date selector in the form, but it shows date and time selectors.

```
     $fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
            ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
            ->setDescription(t('The date that the survey is started.'))
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                'label' => 'above',
                'type' => 'string',
                'weight' => -4,
            ))
            ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                'type' => 'date',
                'weight' => -4,
            ))
            ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
            ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

> [image: screenshot]

How do I show only the date selector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the option on the form and not the field.  The datatime field has an option, `datetime_type` which can be two strings 'date' or 'datetime' (see `DateTimeItem`), and it defaults to 'datetime'.

So, when you are creating your field, you need to update this setting.  The following should work for you:

```
$fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
  ->setDescription(t('The date that the survey is started.'))
  ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'date')
  ->setRequired(true)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

As a side note, when you are having problems like this, the first place to look is at the class implementing the field that you are using, and then look at the tests that cover that field.  Often, you will find the example code that you need.  In this case, you would look at `DateTimeFieldTest` and see what that integration test is doing.

Comment: i am not sure about that, that ll create a varchar type field in mysql... if you want sort on date it's not really the best way

Comment: @Kevin this creates it as a datetime field, so you get all of the stuff that goes along with it (eg, the formatters).  Datetime fields are stored as (mostly) ISO8601 strings which are sortable easily (they are always UTC in storage), indexable, and also easily manipulated in SQL to extract parts.  Date/time manipulation is not standardized between MySQL PostgreSQL, and SQLite, so this last bit can important.  Also, picking nits, but they aren't varchar, they have a hard limit of 20 (will be bumped to 25 soon).